# How can I update my EditText values?

Tags: android, sql-update, android-sqlite

I am new to android , as I am trying to update data using context menu item "EDIT". Using EDIT I will go to `EditText` layout then I will press update Note, But it's  not updating the `EditText` Data.

My Code Database:

```
public void updateNote(String filename, String filedata, String duedate){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues updatenote = new ContentValues();
    updatenote.put(Col_File_Name, filename);
    updatenote.put(Col_File_Data, filedata);
    updatenote.put(Col_Due_Date, duedate);

    db.update(Table_Notepad, updatenote, Col_ID + "=?", null);
    db.close();
}
```

Activity:

```
case R.id.Save:


    String get_title = Title_Edit.getText().toString();
    String get_content = Content_Edit.getText().toString();
    String get_duedate = duedatetext.getText().toString();

    if(!get_title.equals("") || !get_content.equals(""))
    {


     if (!isEdit) {
            //if it isn't edit mode we just add a new note to db

             Database_Notepad db = new Database_Notepad(Add_Task.this);

             db.Create_Note(get_title, get_content, get_duedate);

        } else {
            //if this is edit mode, we just update the old note
             Database_Notepad db = new Database_Notepad(Add_Task.this);

             db.updateNote(get_title, get_content, get_duedate);

            db.close();
        }

    }
```

Please Suggest, I think I need to correct database code. Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: You need to know which row in DB to update, therefore using ID as primary key would be good in this case.

Comment: Check this link it may help you out.. http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/06/edit-row-in-sqlite-database-using.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `updateNote` need Record ID which you want to update.

Like

> public void updateNote(int id, String filename, String filedata, String duedate){

instead

> public void updateNote(String filename, String filedata, String duedate){

and compare that id which your entire record, it will check and update your particular record, change your function function something like below:

```
public void updateNote(int id, String filename, String filedata, String duedate){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues updatenote = new ContentValues();
    updatenote.put(Col_File_Name, filename);
    updatenote.put(Col_File_Data, filedata);
    updatenote.put(Col_Due_Date, duedate);

    db.update(Table_Notepad, updatenote,  "rowid= "+id,, null);// rowid or name of your id column
    db.close();
}
```

and pass the `id` too along with others parameter.

Use

> db.updateNote(id, get_title, get_content, get_duedate);

instead

> db.updateNote(get_title, get_content, get_duedate);

Comment: @Shweta id or position of your record which you want to update.

Answer (score 0):

In `updateNode()`, you need to change this update or insert values:

```
public void updateNote(long rowId, String filename, String filedata, String duedate){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues updatenote = new ContentValues();
    updatenote.put(Col_File_Name, filename);
    updatenote.put(Col_File_Data, filedata);
    updatenote.put(Col_Due_Date, duedate);

    if (rowId >=0)
        db.update(Table_Notepad, updatenote, Col_ID + "=?", new String[] {""+rowId});
    else
        db.insert(Table_Notepad, null, updatenote);
    db.close();
}
```

Then, if you are **creating** a new note you can call:

`updateNote(-1, filename, filedata, duedate);`

and if you are **updating** an existing one, you will have to pass in the ID:

`updateNote(noteRowId, filename, filedata, duedate);`.

**Source**: check these [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29).

Comment: No, if the user wants to modify an existing note then you will need to pass in the row ID somehow.

Comment: Or you set the ID to -1 by default which creates a new note.

Answer (score 0):

Need to pass row id to update in last argument

```
db.update(Table_Notepad, updatenote, Col_ID + "=?", new String[]{id});
```

Happy coding